# drools expert / solver - 5.0.1 matches

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, drools-planner

I am fairly new to drools and I'm running into some issues I can't really understand.
I'm trying to solve an allocation problem and one of my LHS goes like this

```
$leftAlloc: SlotAllocation($leftRes: resource )
$rightAlloc: SlotAllocation(this != $leftAlloc, resource == $leftRes)
```

for some reason the second statement does not match anything even thou I'm sure there is a match in the working memory. If I change the code above with the following it works fine

```
$leftAlloc: SlotAllocation($leftRes: resource )
$rightAlloc: SlotAllocation(this != $leftAlloc, eval(resource == $leftRes))
```

Can anybody explain this to me?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post what your SlotAllocation bean looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off asking this question on the drools user mailing list (use a newsgroup reader to connect to news.gmane.org if you don't want to litter your mailbox).

As for your question: that's really strange. I see only one improbable explanation:

First you should know that `resource == $leftRes)` in the DRL will actually call `getResource().equals($leftRes)`, so it's not a same/pointer check but an equals check.

On the other hand, `eval(resource == $leftRes)` will use a same/pointer check.
So that improbably theory is that your Resource class overwrites the `Object.equals` method and doesn't even return true when it's the same instance...

PS: Continue this discussion on the user mailing list if you have further questions and you want those answered too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Geoffrey, I tried to get access to the drools user mailing list on nabble but I think they are moving from nabble 1.0 to 2.0 and I've never been accepted?

Anyway about the problem i was in contact with jboss and they are looking into that. I know the different between eval and == and I was stepping thru the code and the equals method does not get called at all!

BTW - I'm using your solver and I really like. We might have to extend it a bit (branch and bound?) If that happens I'll definitely try to get in touch with you if you want to include it in the main trunk

Comment: A branch and bound experiment is welcome, just fork us on github and send me a pull request :) I want to implement branch and bound too, but to do it, planner (=solver) needs to know more about the domain (possibly with annotations or something), so that must be done right.

Comment: However, that being said, for my experience, branch and bound does not scale well enough to be used in production use.